# android Two buttons to webpage links

Tags: android, eclipse, button, android-intent

I have been on this for a while now (3 days). I am trying to use Eclipse to make an android app. I want to have two image buttons. Each one linking to a different site. I haven't been able to do it. I have been able to use webview to open one webpage with a button, but not two. I have moved to trying to use Intent instead because I read somewhere that that was the better way. Ultimately, what I want to do is have the page open in the app and use the back button to go back to the main screen of the app for each button/page. Here is my code so far.

MainActivity.java

```
    package com.modsbyus.onoff;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


      }
      public void Light()
     {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,           uri.parse("https://agent.electricimp.com/BGSBpog28J0u?led=1"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
    public void Light1()
    {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,     Uri.parse("https://agent.electricimp.com/BGSBpog28J0u?led=0"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
}
```

and my Layout
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android.onClick="Light1"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcheronswitch" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android.onClick="Light"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcheroffswitch" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help you guys can give would be great. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change the onclick in your xml to android:onClick="onClick" for both buttons and call your methods there in once place. Just for looks.    Make sure your class implements OnClickListener.

Then your onClick method would be :

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent iExp = null;
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.imageButton1:
            iExp = new Intent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://agent.electricimp.com/BGSBpog28J0u?led=1"));
            break;
        case R.id.imageButton2:
            iExp = new Intent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://agent.electricimp.com/BGSBpog28J0u?led=0"));
            break;
    }
        startActivity(iExp);
    }
```

PS onClick on imagebuttons not available till 1.6 and your onClick in the xml has a . when it should be a :

Make sure your manifest has:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Your xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcheronswitch" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcheroffswitch" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Your class:

```
package com.modsbyus.onoff;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
     Intent iExp = null;
     switch (v.getId()) {
     case R.id.imageButton1:
         iExp = new Intent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://agent.electricimp.com/BGSBpog28J0u?led=1"));
         break;
     case R.id.imageButton2:
         iExp = new Intent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://agent.electricimp.com/BGSBpog28J0u?led=0"));
         break;

     }
startActivity(iExp);
 }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I made all the corrections. I used Ricks suggestion. That looked very clean. So now my in my layout I have android:onClick="onClick();" for both buttons. and in my MainActivity I have what Rick said to do, and it compiles fine but force closes when you try to run it. any suggestions?

Comment: Well with out the logcat I am shooting in the dark. I added the permissions you need in your manifest up top.  But you need to post your logcat

Comment: Where in the manifest do those permissions go? Under uses-sdk?

Comment: You can view my log cat http://cloud.modsbyus.com/public.php?service=files&t=d74363ba0e68b03470f7a7be62607b78  it wont let me post it here.

Comment: Its sill trying to call Light1();View.  Make sure no where in your xml file is onClick="Light1"  both should say onClick="onClick"   and right above your application tag for the permissions

Comment: Also uninstall the app from your device, clean, build, and run again.  Sometimes while testing devices get confused with older versions.

Comment: I got it compiled, installed and running. However, it executes the intent for imagebutton2 for both buttons.

Comment: both of your urls say ok how do you know its right?   put http://www.google.com in one and http://www.yahoo.com in the other and try it

Comment: I have a back end I can monitor that tells me what link was used. Besides that I can look at the address in the address bar and see which of the two addresses where used. I took your suggestion and put http://www.google.com in the first intent and uninstalled the previously installed version of the app and recompiled and ran it and still got the link from the second intent for both buttons.

Comment: My Layout http://cloud.modsbyus.com/public.php?service=files&t=b2aa3713012bad937ca64489c636a35d
My Main Activity http://cloud.modsbyus.com/public.php?service=files&t=fd0269038b4bc44f1846e9154798e86d

Comment: You must end each `case` with `break`!! And why the double new Intent in `iExp = new Intent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,...`?

Comment: @ramaral When I insert break; between the th estartActivity(iExp); gives error (Unreachable code). As for the double iExp = new Intent(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,.. I am very new and trying to learn. Rick suggested that code and with the exception of the first and second button executing the 2nd intent instead of the intended intent it works. I am open to any lessons you may have.

Comment: Move `startActivity(iExp);` to after the bracket. Consider applying what I propose in my answer, it is much easier.

Comment: Can you point me to a good resource about intents? I am having a hard time understanding how to properly format it. This code works well now after inserting the breaks and moving the startactivity. Thanks!!!

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html   Can you please check mark the answer it will help others in the future.

Comment: Before go to more complex stuff, try learn better the JAVA language and the Android programing philosophy

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the xml attribute `android:onClick="methodName"` you need to declare a public method that returns void and accepts a View as parameter, with same name as defined in `onClick="methodName"`.

What you need in your code is only add the parameter View to methods Light and Light1.
So, change:

```
public void Light()
public void Light1()
```

to:

```
public void Light(View v)
public void Light1(View v)
```

And, as **Rick** sugested, change `android.onClick=` to `android:onClick=`